# Is there a name for this formula involving the product of matrix exponentials?

Tags: matrices, limits, terminology, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ and $B$ be two (not necessarily commuting) matrices of order $n$. Then

$$\mathop{\lim}\limits_{t \to 0}e^{-tB}e^{-tA}e^{tB}e^{tA} = e^{t^2[B,A] + o(t^3)}$$

I recall coming across this formula at various times but can't seem to find a reference for it. Is there a recognized name for it?

Comment: Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff ?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Comment: Maybe the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula is of help here.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: I seem to recall that BCH is used in the proof, but that the formula itself is given its own name.

Comment: Suzuki Trotter?